# Export to Excel .xlsx File

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbdataadapter

I' m trying to export xlsx file with these codes:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(select, accessConnection);
adapter.Update(dataTable);
```

The connection string is

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AA\Desktop\work10.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

I' m trying to export 200000 rows to xlsx file but getting *spreadsheet is full* error.
When I try to open the excel file, I' m getting *file extension is not valid* error.

After changing .xlsx extension to .xls, file is opening but row count is not enough for me.

Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 version is installed to the computer.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does it still happen if you add the `IMEX=1` option to the connection string?

Comment: It causes another problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [that the OLEDB Excel driver is limited to 65536 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25929789/87698). Thus, you cannot use your current code to export 200000 rows. Sorry, it just won't work, and there's no way you can make it work.

If you need to write more than 65536 rows, you need to use another Excel export mechanism, for example, [a third-party C# Excel library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/151005/87698), or consider using another file format such as CSV.

Comment: I know .xls is limited so I'm trying to export .xlsx file. My ConnectionString seems suitable for .xlsx files

Comment: @user1451549: Apparently, it's not only a limitation of the xls file format but also a limitation of the OLEDB driver (xls and xlsx). Your connection string looks fine.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll ask another question when I try to export less than 65536 rows, export finishes successfully. After that I' m trying to open exported xlsx file, I get 'Excel can not open the test.xlsx because file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file' error. How can I solve it?

Comment: I asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012472/export-excel-file-with-xlsx-extension